# Can I upload 13TB(folders and files) to OneDrive or SharePoint and do collaborate work with that files?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document, file, onedrive, limitations

I need to upload all folders since my company PC to SharePoint for collaboration work with that, but I don't know if it is possible because if I synchronize with OneDrive the space is limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sharepoint limit：**

Max storage per site (site collection) is 25 TB.
In a SharePoint Online subscription you will get 1 TB plus 10 GB per license purchased space by default.You could split the data between various Sitecollections. It is normal for an organization to have 100's-1000's of site collections.
If you wish to add additional space to the 1TB you need to purchase more storage which is available on the on the Site Collections page inside SharePoint admin or on the subscriptions page inside Office 365 Admin.

**Onedrive limit:**

You get 5 GB of free storage when you sign up for OneDrive.Microsoft 365 subscribers can buy up to 2 TB of OneDrive storage.

So onedrive can't store 13TB files, sharepoint can.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-your-onedrive-storage-and-limits-989fce19-ade6-4e2f-81fb-941eabefee28

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.